# Whenever I enter 4.2 in this code, the value of nm is 19, where 20 is expected

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to get 20 in the variable nm.  But it is returning 19.

How do I fix it? And what is causing this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    float m;

    int n = 0;
    do {
         m = get_float("Enter:");

        }while(m < 0);
    int nm =(m * 100 );
    while(nm >= 25 ){
        nm = nm - 25;
        n = n + 1;

    }

    printf("%i\n",n);
    printf("%i\n", nm);
}
```

Comment: And that, kids, is why we don't *ever* rely on transitive equality when pushing a float through an `int`.

Comment: It's very tempting just to close this as a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit `float` can encode about 2<sup>32</sup> different values *exactly*.  Due to the binary nature of the typical [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), 4.2 is not one of them.

Instead `m` has the value of `4.1999998...`

```
// closest float
4.19999980926513671875
// hoped for value
4.2
// next closest float
4.200000286102294921875
```

Multiplexing by 100 incurs some rounding and the best answer to `m*100` is then `419.999969482421875`.

`int nm =(m * 100 );` results `nm == 419` as assignment of a `float` to `int` truncates the fractional portion away.

---

Consider rounding to the nearest integer rather than truncating via `int` assignment and use `double` constants.

```
#include <math.h>

// int nm =(m * 100 );
int nm = lround(m * 100.0);
// or 
int nm = round(m * 100.0);
```